# Desalinhamento do título e tags para perguntas nas páginas iniciais

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Nas páginas iniciais, tanto do [site principal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) quanto [Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), existe um desalinhamento no título e tags da pergunta que é causado pelo "s" do texto "respostas" que faz o quadradinho verde ficar maior do que o quadradinho que tem o texto "resposta".

Conforme imagem abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que olhos você tem. Não é um papagaio ai na foto, e sim uma águia! :p... kkkkk

Comment: @ÉrikThiago hahaha.. eu vi isso ontem, e me incomodou bastante, só resta saber se já tá assim faz tempo ou não :P

Comment: Eu nem tinha percebido. Mas olhando com mais perícia, me parece que fica mesmo desalinhado...